# Publish development version of NPM package

Tags: node.js, npm

How can I publish development version of NPM package?

I tried to set `"dev"` value for `version` field in `package.json` but I got an error when publishing it:

```
$ npm publish
npm ERR! Error: Invalid version: "dev"
npm ERR!     at Object.module.exports.fixVersionField (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/fixer.js:180:13)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/normalize.js:29:38
npm ERR!     at Array.forEach (native)
npm ERR!     at normalize (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/normalize.js:28:15)
npm ERR!     at final (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:310:33)
npm ERR!     at then (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:124:33)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:299:40
npm ERR!     at fs.js:266:14
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:103:5
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-15-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "publish"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ionicabizau/package-name
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.23
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ionicabizau/package-name/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Which are the closest alternatives?

Comment: You can publish `1.0.0-dev`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NPM package version must meet requirements of [semver](https://npmjs.org/doc/misc/semver.html)

> A normal version number MUST take the form X.Y.Z where X, Y, and Z are
>   non-negative integers, and MUST NOT contain leading zeroes. X is the
>   major version, Y is the minor version, and Z is the patch version.
>   Each element MUST increase numerically. For instance: 1.9.0 -> 1.10.0
>   -> 1.11.0.

So using `dev` as a version number is not allowed.

Also it is not recommended to publish any code which is in development state. If you want to test your module within different module you can include that module using relative path or using git remote URL.

**Example:**

Let's say that the module which you are developing is called `foo` and you would like to test it in module `bar`, script file `bar/index.js`. Let's assume both module directories are in the same parent directory. Instead of publishing *unfinished* module `foo` to [npm](https://npmjs.org) and install it in module `bar`, you can do as follows:

```
var foo = require('../foo')
```

As suggested by [Ionicã Bizãu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1420197/ionic%c3%a3-biz%c3%a3u) (comments below), you can also use npm install with git remote URL e.g.

```
npm install <git remote url>
```

[NPM install documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install.html) provides more details (option g) on that installation method.

Alternatively you can use approach proposed in this post: [Locally test your npm modules without publishing them to npmjs.org](http://podefr.tumblr.com/post/30488475488/locally-test-your-npm-modules-without-publishing-them).

**EDIT**

There is another alternative solution which require `npm link` [command](https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-link.html):

- Execute `npm link` command inside your developed module. That will create globally-installed symbolic link from `prefix/package-name` to the current folder
- Another step is to execute `npm link package-name` (where `package-name` is a name of your developed package) in some other location (other module / application which you use to test the developed module). That will create a symlink from the local node_modules folder to the global symlink (which was created in the first step).

Note that you may need to run the first command as a privileged user (usually `sudo` helps) in some operating systems.

With symlinks in place you will be able to add changes to your developed module and see their results instantly in other *linked* modules.

I hope that will help.

Comment: Hey, can you please update your answer that `npm install` command supports the git repository url, so the dev version will be installed?  e.g. `npm install git://github.com/user/repo.git`

Comment: @IonicãBizãu, thank you for your suggestion; very handy option!

Comment: The option with `npm pack` is the best one for me so far. Less hacking, less overhead, avoid publishing codes, very fast.

Answer (score 38):

You can [upload prerelease tags to npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#prerelease-tags). These tags will not be matched by normal semver range semantics, but will allow you to both use and upload development versions. An example would be `1.3.5-alpha.3`. If you're uploading something that has no version yet, then a reasonable use would be something like `0.0.1-alpha.1`.

Comment: Oh, that sounds good, and actually I used to do this, but after `npm publish`ing such a version, `npm install` will install the stable version (not alpha?)

Comment: yes. the only way to use the alpha is to specify the alpha tag when installing.

Comment: Got it, accepted answer–much better and actually expected behavior. :)