# Npm development versions for libraries

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Recently I've seen a library (react-3d-components) that has some d3 react components with some basic charts to use. It's a cool set of components.

However, when I want to see the source code, because the documentation is not quite complete yet, and when you want to see how to extend a component, for example, you found yourself looking at the transpiled version of the code. Not nice. I would like to see the human readable version of the source code. Fine. Usually packages have the sources built in so you just find within your IDE the human readable version of the file. If you're lucky you have source-maps. But here is where it gets complicated.

This module, in github, has his entire human readable source code, which is fine and correct, and, because of a .npmignore file, it is just publishing the transpiled version of the files. When I saw this I was about to create a new issue, when I realised that the guy has a point: it reduces the package size by not packing unnecessary files. But that applies to runtime, in development time (in my computer) I want the entire source code and with source-maps so I can navigate through the code and read it. Also this may apply to some assets too. I think it will be nice some kind of development version of the package.

See the ignore line here:
https://github.com/codesuki/react-d3-components/blob/master/.npmignore#L2

So I wonder... how should I create a library when I create one? With a development package version and a production/default version? (eg. mypackage-with-sources@1.0-dev) Or should I leave that to the IDE and use some plugin that integrates the source code with repo page somehow using http? Or there is an official support by npm for this that I don't know about? (I tried to search for it I couldn't find anything)

I also read this post: [Publish development version of NPM package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355508/publish-development-version-of-npm-package)

But it doesn't offer a good solution. The most convincing one is to use prerelease tags like alpha or beta, but it is not correct. The other solution suggests to install the github/vendor repository, which may be correct but is unconvienent  and uncomfortable for development purposes (and more important, not always available, not all npm packages are from known/accesible http repositories).

Any best practice (with reasons) about this would be well received besides of the concrete answer.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Sources should be part of the package, because they are useful for development, and package size should not matter at runtime: in node, node will only load files that are actually require'd, in the browser reasonable people use bundlers (such as webpack) that only bundle required files.

Size of the package therefore only matters for package download and storage. Package download occurs rarely due to npm's caching, and disk space is cheap enough that we can afford storing a few MB of source code, though I would stop short of including architecture diagrams as images, like I once saw a certain library doing.

The [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package) of .npmignore also hints that .npmignore is intended to exclude transient files (like .gitignore). If .npmignore were intended to exclude source code, the npm docs would tell you.

Comment: I know that the source is not needed by the runtime, and about the cache that npm uses.
However, reducing the package size for the runtime scenario, BECAUSE of the files that are wasting storage, does not look like a bad choice. Yes we can include everything, that's what almost everyone is doing (including myself), but this package react-3d-components has this different and it made me thought he may be right.
I'm trying to explore new alternatives before posting an issue that is not an issue.
I couldn't find anything about transient file in the documentation neither...

Comment: The source code of this package is 67 KB. At google cloud, where [a GB currently costs $0.02 per month](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing), storing sources for this package would therefore cost each user $0.00000134 per month. For a user to visit github to locate the source will take a few minutes, or, at a minimum wage of $7 per hour, about $0.5.

Comment: It doesn't address the point of my question. Your suggestion is to forget about it. It is not an answer.

Comment: You asked whether there is a standard for development versions of libraries. My answer is that the standard is including the source in the package, because there is no real gain in separating the source, as doing so incurs no runtime overhead, and storage is so cheap that saving a few KB is not worth anyone's time. Feel free to waste your time though.

Comment: I asked for best practices not for standards. And I mentioned in my question that including the source is what is common. So... I should assume that you didn't even read the whole question. Is not just a few KBs when you have hundreds of dependencies among hundreds of projects.

Comment: 100*100*67 KB = 0.67 GB, which still costs less than a cent per month ... but yes, I understand you don't want to hear that and shall refrain from further comment.

Comment: 1) the price is not a constant, 2) You may have more than a hundred (I said hundreds not just a hundred, any common project has more than 500 folders in their node_modules) 3) Is not that I don't want to hear that, is that you're not saying nothing new