# What is the 'dev' dependency version?

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, version, package.json

What is the 'dev' dependency version?

E.g. [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e2dlnf-2pxxnk?file=package.json):

```
{
  "name": "ntbjpb--run",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@progress/kendo-angular-progressbar": "^0.2.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-toolbar": "dev",
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.1",
    ...
  }
}
```

`"@progress/kendo-angular-toolbar": "dev"`

I tried to google it, but all my research comes to the `devDependencies` which is not what I am looking for I guess.

The best match I got was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355508/publish-development-version-of-npm-package) question. But the answer to it states:

> So using dev as a version number is not allowed.

While we can clearly see from the stackblitz example I linked above that it is not the case and the `dev` is allowed to be used in the place of the version number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That string mean `install the module tag <dev>` as reported in docs [`npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<tag>`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install)

In fact, looking [the versions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@progress/kendo-angular-toolbar) of that module you will see the tag defined:

[image: module tagging]

Comment: So, in this particular case using the `dev` is essentially just an alias for the `3.2.1-dev.202011180826`. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: In this time frame, yes it is, but the `dev` tag is updated whenever the maintainer decides to update that tag. Instead `3.2.1-dev.202011180826` is a defined version that you can install by `@progress/kendo-angular-toolbar@3.2.1-dev.202011180826`

Comment: So, should I run the `npm update @progress/kendo-angular-toolbar@3.2.1-dev.202011180826` if I want to get the current `dev` tagged version to my local app?

Comment: no, you should run `npm install @progress/kendo-angular-toolbar@3.2.1-dev.202011180826` since you want to lock the version in this case